# Get compile time type of member of Generic'd object

Tags: typescript, types, helper

I'm trying to make a function that simplifies the setting of `set`ter functions on objects that can be used for arbitrary purposes. Obvious uses include type guards, value and bound checking, or triggering events.

The idea is to take an object of known shape and have a function that you call on it that returns a new object of the same enumerable shape where each of the object's members actually have `set` and `get` "Properties". The `set`ters come from a second parameter to the function and the `get`ters simply return the "protected" value.

A large amount of the utility of this method comes from the possible strict typings. This is particularly useful when the protected object is defined in separate sections of code that might even be out of your control. If the object shape changes, type errors will ensure new `set`ters are added/removed.

I created a "flat" version pretty easily.

#### Flat version

```
function makeObjectSetter<T extends {}>(
  internal: T,
  setters: {
    [P in keyof T]: (next: T[P]) => void;
  }
) {
  const ret = {};

  for (const x in internal) {
    Object.defineProperty(ret, x, {
      set: setters[x],
      get: () => internal[x],
      enumerable: true,
    });
  }

  return ret as T;
}
```

### Usage

```
const myObject = {
  num: 42,
  str: 'initialValue',
};

const protectedObject = makeObjectSetter(myObject, {
  num(x) {
    // Make sure positive
    myObject.num = Math.max(x, 0);
  },
  str(s) {
    // Always double the input
    myObject.str = s + s;
  },
});

console.log(myObject);
// { num: 42, str: 'initialValue' }

protectedObject.num = -1;
protectedObject.str = 'a';

console.log(myObject);
// { num: 0, str: 'aa' }

for (let x in protectedObject) console.log(x);
// num
// str
```

The tricky part comes when the target object has nested objects. While the flat version could be used, it gets cumbersome to write the deeper the nesting.

So, I'm trying to write a recursive version of the flat function. This detects if the type of the member is an object and treats that differently. I believe I have the function signature types correct, but there is one hard error inside the function on a single line that I cannot figure out.

I'm aware of TypeScript types not being available at runtime, but I believe this is a compile time issue. I believe if I get the right syntax on the noted line, it will work. But maybe I'm wrong?

#### Recursive Version

```
type NestedSetters<T extends {}> = { [P in keyof T]: T[P] extends {} ? NestedSetters<T[P]> : (next: T[P]) => void };

function makeObjectSetterRecursive<T extends {}>(internal: T, setters: NestedSetters<T>) {
  const ret = {};

  for (const x in internal) {
    let prop: PropertyDescriptor;

    // Can't figure out this line
    type t = typeof internal[x];

    // Pretty sure this test is the right runtime test for my purposes
    if (typeof internal[x] == 'object') {
      prop = {
        value: makeObjectSetterRecursive(internal[x], setters[x] as NestedSetters<t>), // Should be able to avoid this `as` cast, no?
      };
    } else {
      prop = {
        set: setters[x] as (next: t) => void, // Should be able to avoid this `as` cast, no?
        get: () => internal[x],
      };
    }

    prop.enumerable = true;

    Object.defineProperty(ret, x, prop);
  }

  return ret as T; // Extra extra bonus get rid of this `as` cast
}
```

Beside `typeof internal[x]`, I've also tried `Pick<typeof internal, x>` and other guesses to no avail.

Any thoughts on this would be greatly appreciated. The answer might be that what I want is not possible.

Side quest: I feel like the `as` casts should not be necessary with the correct type hinting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned, TypeScript types are not available at runtime and therefore `typeof internal[x]` cannot work. What you are looking for is `T[Extract<keyof T, string>]`, which extracts the type of your prop's value.

Regarding the casting problems, there seems to be an issue with conditional type narrowing.
https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30152
Therefore, one must rely on the runtime logic in the if else statement mapping the correct type (in this case `typeof value === 'object'`). For semantics, I thought it useful to make a user defined type guard `isNestedSetters` and casting the values to a union type `NestedSetters<T[P]> | Setter<T[P]>`, because this the compiler can narrow correctly.

Here is the full version:

```
type Setter<T> = T extends boolean ? (next: boolean) => void : (next: T) => void

type SetterOrNested<T> = T extends object ? NestedSetters<T> : Setter<T>

type NestedSetters<T> = {
  [P in keyof T]: SetterOrNested<T[P]>
}

function isNestedSetters<T>(value: any): value is NestedSetters<T> {
  return typeof value === 'object';
}

function makeObjectSetterRecursive<T extends {}>(internal: T, setters: NestedSetters<T>) {
  const ret = <T>{};

  for (const x in internal) {
    let prop: PropertyDescriptor;

    type P = Extract<keyof T, string>

    const setterOrNested = setters[x] as NestedSetters<T[P]> | Setter<T[P]>

    if (isNestedSetters<T[P]>(setterOrNested)) {
      prop = {
        value: makeObjectSetterRecursive(internal[x], setterOrNested),
      };
    } else {
      prop = {
        set: setterOrNested,
        get: () => internal[x],
      };
    }

    prop.enumerable = true;

    Object.defineProperty(ret, x, prop);
  }

  return ret;
}
```

which should outputs the following:

```
const myObject = {
  num: 42,
  str: 'initialValue',
  others: {
    bool: true,
    nestedStr: ''
  }
};

const protectedObject = makeObjectSetterRecursive(myObject, {
  num(x) {
    // Make sure positive
    myObject.num = Math.max(x, 0);
  },
  str(s) {
    // Always double the input
    myObject.str = s + s;
  },
  others: {
    bool(b) {
      // Toggle
      myObject.others.bool = !b
    },
    nestedStr(s) {
      // Add 3 dots
      myObject.others.nestedStr = s + '...'
    }
  }
});

console.log(myObject);
// { num: 42, str: 'initialValue', others: { bool: true, nestedStr: '' } }

protectedObject.num = -1;
protectedObject.str = 'a';
console.log(myObject);
// { num: 0, str: 'aa', others: { bool: true, nestedStr: '' } }

protectedObject.others.bool = true;
protectedObject.others.nestedStr = 'abc';
console.log(myObject);
// { num: 0, str: 'aa', others: { bool: false, nestedStr: 'abc...' } }
```

I must say, I am not so sure about the use case for this, but it is an interesting concept, so I decided to give it a go anyway.

Comment: Yes! The `Extract<keyof T, string>` is what I was missing. Looks like there was also a typing issue with the setter object on my code but your's addresses the problem! I'm considering packaging this code up as a reusable npm module. Would you mind if I used your implementation? I'll gladly include you in the contributor list (or where ever you think is appropriate). I'd also be happy if you wanted to run with it instead.

Comment: Sure, go for it. The contributor list makes sense to me. Keep me posted :)